# How do you support mixed arithmetic with a user defined class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm curious as to how to support mixed arithmetic using a user-defined class in python. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html) state

> Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic
>   operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the
>   “narrower” type is widened to that of the other, where integer is
>   narrower than floating point, which is narrower than complex.

The behavior I am trying to recreate can be seen with numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])

a + 5
Out[3]: array([6, 7, 8])

5 + a
Out[4]: array([6, 7, 8])
```

If I try to do this with a user defined class, I get something like this

```
from decimal import Decimal


class MyType:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = Decimal(str(value))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<MyType {self.value}>'

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyType):
            other = MyType(other)
        return MyType(self.value + other.value)
```

Then attempting to do something similar gives an error when the first addition argument is a float instead of my class.

```
a = MyType(.1)

a + 5
Out[14]: <MyType 5.1>

5 + a
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-35e25b55bb62>", line 1, in <module>
    5 + a

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'MyType'
```

Comment: I think this post describes a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745595/automatic-type-conversions-of-user-defined-classes/36745772

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic type conversions of user defined classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745595/automatic-type-conversions-of-user-defined-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can define both `__add__` and [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

So the easiest thing in your case to do is to add `__radd__ = __add__`

```
from decimal import Decimal

class MyType:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = Decimal(str(value))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<MyType {self.value}>'

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyType):
            other = MyType(other)
        return MyType(self.value + other.value) 
    
    __radd__ = __add__
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn’t aware of those built in functions to represent a numeric type. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems something like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289093/can-you-impose-object-precedence-for-overloaded-operators-in-python).

```
from decimal import Decimal

class MyType:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = Decimal(str(value))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<MyType {self.value}>'
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyType):
            other = MyType(other)
        return MyType(self.value + other.value)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyType):
            other = MyType(other)
        return MyType(self.value + other.value)
```