# Multiple operator overloading in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have 2 point classes with `+` operator overloading:

```
class Point2D:
    x = 0
    y = 0

    def __add__(self, __other: "Point2D"):
        return Point2D(self.x + __other.x, self.y + __other.y)

class Point3D(Point2D):
    z = 0

    def __add__(self, __other: "Point3D"):
        return Point3D(self.x + __other.x, self.y + __other.y, self.z + __other.z)
```

I can add 2 points of the same type, but I also want to be able to add 2 points of different types, for example:

```
>>> print(Point2D(1, 2) + Point3D(0, 1, 2))
(1, 3, 2)
```

I tried overloading the operator again with a different type expected like this (inside the Point3D class):

```
def __add__(self, __other: "Point2D"):
        return Point3D(self.x + __other.x, self.y + __other.y, self.z)
```

but it doesn't recognize them as 2 different functions and just chooses the last one (my guess is because expected type parameters are only a suggestion in python and in practice it's all just an object so it has the same function signature). Is there a way to do this without resorting to `isinstance()` cases inside the function?

Comment: You can only have one method with a given name in each class. It will need to use `if` to determine whether `__other` is a `Point2D` or `Point3D` and do the right hting.

Comment: `a + b` will always try `a.__add__(b)` first. `b.__add__(a)` only gets called if that first method call returns `NotImplemented` (to say _"I can't handle this"_). So maybe Point2D should only handle addition with other Point2Ds, then Point3D takes over in mixed cases? See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: @jonrsharpe Isn't it also possible to define `Point3D.__radd__()` to handle `Point2D + Point3D`?

Comment: @Barmar yes, but you'd still need `Point2D.__add__` so say "not for me", which @OP means an isinstance check.

Comment: Good point. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289093/can-you-impose-object-precedence-for-overloaded-operators-in-python) is relevant.

Comment: radd will work for this case but im trying to find a more "scalable" solution(adding point4D, Point5D for example all working with each other). from several sources i checked before posting i understood that its a 1 time solution but maybe i misunderstood them.

Answer (score -1):

By creating a custom decorator you can assign different functions depending on the type. Here is a simplified example :

```py
custom_func = {}

def ontype(_type):
    def decorated(original):
        custom_func[_type] = original
        def func(self, other):
            return custom_func[type(other)](self, other)
        return func
    return decorated

class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.value))

    @ontype(int)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return int(self.value+other)

    @ontype(float)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return float(self.value+other)

    @ontype(str)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return str(self.value)+" "+other

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(CustomClass(5)+5.0)
    print(CustomClass(5)+5)
    print(CustomClass(5)+"FIVE")
```

And the output is :

```
10.0
10
5 FIVE
```

As you can see here, defining multiple times the `__add__` method is not getting rid of the predefined ones, thanks to the decorator. In this example I'm just putting them in a dict, but there are several ways of doing it, depends really on the usage

Comment: Both of those additions should return a Point3D, and the addition of two Point3Ds wouldn't work correctly either.

Comment: Ok I see. I edited, maybe the new version will suits what you are looking for

Comment: i was looking for a solution without type checking inside the __add__ function similar to how c++ does operator overloading. you can overload as many times as you want with different types expected(meaning different function signature). so for every object you want to deal with you write a different function, and when you write a + b it finds the function with the matching signature of type B parameter in the type A class.

Comment: Ok I see. I edited showing a way to decorate multiple times the function using a type, please have a look :)